# node.js mongodb client :Cannot call method 'collection' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

this is my data.config file

```
DbProvider.prototype.doOperation = function(collection, operation, params, callback)
 {
    this.validateParams(params, callback);

var operationCallback = function(err, result)
{

    callback(err, result);
};
this.db.collection(collection, function(err, collection) {
    if(operation==='find') {
        collection.find().toArray(operationCallback);
    } else {
        collection[operation](params, operationCallback);
    }
});
}

DbProvider.prototype.findUser = function(params, callback)
 {

   this.doOperation('users', 'findOne', params, callback);

 };
```

i have tried to find id exit or not by this way

```
dbProvider.findUser({_id:"514fdb464f2c06a9d6003afb"},function(err,result)

{

console.log("welcome");

});
```

but i got this error  Cannot call method 'collection' of null
how to resolve this...

Comment: It looks like this.db is null?

Comment: var MongoClient       = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var DbProvider = function(host, port, database) {

   this.dbUrl = "mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/"+database;
                
};                                                                                                                                      DbProvider.prototype.connect = function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    MongoClient.connect(this.dbUrl, function(err, db){
        self.db = db;
        callback();
    });
};
this is my mongodb connection .this is in data.config file.now tell me

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that `DbProvider` has the `db` field in it? As @AndrewBarrett said, it seems like it does not, which is indicative of either a scoping issue (`DbProvider` does not own a `db` field) or `DbProvider` does not have the `db` field at a particular time when `doOperation` is called. Perhaps this is an edge case and a simple check to see if `this.db` inside `doOperation` should be made before calling `collection` on `this.db`.